# Uploadify and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, uploadify

So I'm working on a site that needs picture and video uploads. As a result I have decided to use uploadify. I have been trying to control what stylesheets and javascript files are expressed per page. I think this is what is affecting my uploadify function but I can't be sure so I thought I would try.

JQuery and Uploadify declaration in footer

```
<!-- begin jquery scripting -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/poles/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<?php if(strcmp(htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']),'/poles/index.php') == 0){   ?><script src="/poles/js/loginValidation.js"></script><?php } ?>
<?php if(strcmp(htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']),'/poles/about.php') == 0){   ?><script src="/poles/js/regValidation.js"></script><?php } ?>
<?php if(strcmp(htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']),'/poles/account.php') == 0){ ?><script type="text/javascript" src="/poles/uploadify/jquery.uploadify.min.js"></script><?php } ?>
<!-- end jquery scripting -->
```

Stylesheet and uploadify script declaration

```
<?php if(strcmp(htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']),'/poles/account.php') == 0){ ?><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/poles/uploadify/uploadify.css" /><?php } ?>
    <?php if(strcmp(htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']),'/poles/account.php') == 0){ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#file_upload').uploadify({
                'swf'      : '/poles/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
                'uploader' : '/poles/uploadify/uploadify.php'
                // Put your options here
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php } ?>
```

Finally I have the file input required declared in a function in a separate php file like so

```
//user pictures
function diplayPictureUpdate($userId){
    $currDisplayPicture =
    '
        <input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" />
    ';

    return $currDisplayPicture;

}
```

All I get is the normal file button with no option to upload multiple files.

Comment: Are you sure your uploadify css and js is loaded? can you please check it once from its source code?

Comment: Yes sir I'm sure. I checked the page source and when I click the links I get the actual js or CSS.